# Why they are Zariski open subsets?

Tags: lie-algebras, zariski-topology

The following is the definition of Zariski topology
[image]

I am reading a theorem of Lie algebra.In its proof,he says U and R are Zariski open subsets: [image]

I have problems in geting the polynomials and showing that they aren't the common zeros of these polynomials. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions on a linear operator to be nilpotent, respectively singular, are polynomial in whatever coordinates you introduce on your space(s). Indeed, if $T$ is a linear operator on a space of dimension $N$, then $T$ is nilpotent if and only if $T^N = 0$ - and $T^N$ entries (matrix elements if you will) are polynomial in the matrix elements of $T$; and $T$ is singular if and only if $\det T = 0$, and $\det$ is also polynomial in $T$.

Comment: Yes, the first can be seen as a polynomial of T. But can you tell me how to view det as a polynomial in T(just let T be a matrix)

Comment: To fix ideas, take a two-dimensional space with coordinates $x_1, x_2$. Then linear operators on that space form a **four** dimensional space, with coordinates $a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21}, a_{22}$. The determinant is $a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21}$, a polynomial in the coordinates. Note that $T^N = 0$ is not **one** polynomial equation but many - it's an equality of matrices, meaning $n^2$ different equations if the underlying vector space has dimension $n$.

Comment: It says that U and R are Zariski open subsets of $h$,.so I think the variable of the polynomials are the whole matrix,not the coordinates of the matrix. Could you tell me why you use the polynomials in coordinates?

Comment: $h \in \mathfrak h$; the coordinates are on $\mathfrak h$ and they identify the element $h$. Then $adh$ is a linear operator, and its "coordinates" (matrix elements) are polynomial (actually linear) in the coordinates of $h$. Combine this with what we discussed before.